# TypeError only using google chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, file-upload

Since two days I have an error when I upload files in AJAX ft. angularJS using this script https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload .
But just after I select the file I want to upload, I have a TypeError:

TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at TypeError (native)

```
at upload (http://localhost:8888/angular-file-upload.min.js:2:1609)
at h.$scope.onFileSelect (http://localhost/UploadCtrl.js:31:29)
at http://localhost/angular.min.js:166:92
at http://localhost/angular-file-upload.min.js:2:1991
at http://localhost/angular.min.js:115:185
at e (http://localhost:8888/angular.min.js:33:421)
at http://localhost:8888/angular.min.js:37:77
```

If I use an other browser like Firefox,Safari,Opera, even IE, all work fine..

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Post your UploadCtrl.js so we can see where the type error is coming from.

Comment: Also, when debugging don't use minified files !!!

Comment: of course, I don't use minified file I've just change the content of *.min files with the dev version file without changing the name. 
It doesn't come from the UploadCtrl since I've updated the angular-file-upload.. it comes from this one precisely.. You can check the file on the github repo.

Answer (score 1):

Angular expects the file that is uploaded to implement the Blob interface.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

I had this error in a Jasmine test and solved it by creating a new Blob like this.

var file = new Blob();